# How to download original image resolution

Tags: images, download, preview

I saw [How to get the full image when the shopping site like Amazon shows you only a part of the image and let you zoom and pan?](https://superuser.com/questions/123911/how-to-get-the-full-image-when-the-shopping-site-like-amazon-shows-you-only-a-pa) and found some good info but all posts appeared like Klingon to me as I am a moderate-level of internet user with slight-to-no knowledge about HTML or for that matter lines like "SCR value" and "start stripping out all of the encumbering SCR in parentheses". These were out of the world to me.

Can someone please look at this [image](http://www.flipkart.com/total-recall-dil-chahta-hai/p/itmdmdtzbpzcqhzh?pid=AVMDMDTGFBN4GS43&otracker=from-search&srno=t_3&query=Total%20Recall&ref=5f52e5a3-df6b-4745-8d18-6f851883fe8c), hover at the image beside and tell me how to download the zoom resolution in **one piece** – and tell me how to do it for other images as well. step-by-step?

Now to suspicious people, I have bought the CD, ripped it in 320kbps in MP3 and want to have it an album art. The problem is I don't have a scanner, plus these images look very good as they're done by a professional.

Comment: What internet browser do you use?

Comment: The preview is probably good enough for album art - most embedded album art is pretty low resolution

Comment: If you see it, it is often found in your net temps. A web spider, or sniffer could pull it easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This technique will only work for that particular website:

1. View the HTML source of the page. Depending on your browser, you should be able to right-click in an empty area of the page and select **View Page Source**. Alternatively, look for a menu option like:

   - **View > Developer > View Source**
   - **Tools > Web Developer > Page Source**
2. Search for **`data-zoom-src`** within the HTML source (by pressing Ctrl-F, for example).
3. You should find a line of code which looks like this:

   ```
   data-zoom-src="http://img8a.flixcart.com/image/av-media/music/s/4/3/total-recall-dil-chahta-hai-1100x1100-imadmdv7sud9g6nz.jpeg" />
   ```
4. The link to the full-size image is in-between the two `"` symbols:

   ```
   http://img8a.flixcart.com/image/av-media/music/s/4/3/total-recall-dil-chahta-hai-1100x1100-imadmdv7sud9g6nz.jpeg
   ```
5. Load that link in your browser, and you'll see the full-size image.
6. Right-click on the image, and select **Save Image As...** (or similar menu option).